# ReactDOM is not rendering the code that is passed to the root

Tags: reactjs

I am currently doing Learn React JS  YouTube tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLX62G4lc44&t=854s.

I am stuck in the beginning itself. I am working on VS Code instead of Scrimba. I believe it should work despite. I also installed dependencies through npm(react and react-dom). I also installed http-server for local host. It is not throwing any error nor is rendering the DOM elements. Here is the code I have right now...

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html lang="en">
    
      <head>
    
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
            <title>My React App</title>
    
            <style rel="stylesheet" src="style.css"></style>
    
        </head>
    
        <body>
    
            <div id="root"></div>
    
            <script type="text/babel" src="index.pack.js"></script>
    
        </body>
    
    </html>
```

index.js

````
    import React from "react"
    
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
    
    ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello</h1> ,document.getElementById("root"))
    ```
  
package.json
````

```
{

  "name": "myreactapp",

  "version": "1.0.0",

  "type": "module",

  "description": "My first react app",

  "main": "index.js",

  "dependencies": {

    "html-server": "^0.1.1",

    "http-server": "^0.12.3",

    "install": "^0.13.0",

    "npm": "^6.14.8",

    "react": "^17.0.1",

    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"

  },

  "devDependencies": {},

  "scripts": {

    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"

  },

  "author": "",

  "license": "ISC"

}
```

```
Please help me resolve this

Thank you
NSKP
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an `App.js` file, if not create one.

**App.js:**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In your `index.js` file import the `App.js` file and render it.

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Edit:**

You might be wondering why do we need an `App.js` file and an `index.js` file.

An `index.js` file is the entry point for all node apps and you keep what code and where that code needs to be rendered.

An `App.js` file is the root component of your entire React application. React follows a unidirectional model where the code starts of from the `App` component(top most component) and scaffolds down like in a hierarchical model. Not saying you cannot have the `App` component in the `index.js` file but you should follow this order as it is the convention followed by the community.

```
-> App Component(First Component)
--> Secondary Component
---> Third Component
// and so on.
```

Comment: Why does it need App.js file?( Sorry I am new to React)                                                   
             BTW, it is still not rendering

Comment: How did you create the project? Did you use ```npx create-react-app```? Also I updated the answer with an explanation.

Comment: No, I was following the Youtube tutorial... That guy uses scrimba and does from scratch..But I used VS Code and added dependencies through npm. I also tried scaffolding through create-react-app which was successful. But I want to learn what is causing the problem if building from scratch

Comment: My guess is the error is due to the index.js file. Could you double check that the paths are correct?